# Launch wedriver using webdrivermanager from excelsheet?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, webdriver-manager

Is there a way to read browsername from excel and launch URL using webdrivermanager instead of specifying it in application. Properties

Comment: You can set the path to the driver using `System.setProperty`.

Comment: Since I'm using QAF with webdrivermanager.. No need of system.setproperty